# The issue lies in the received data from the serial port

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, scale

I have developed a scale application that reads data from a serial port and displays it in a text box. However, I have a problem with the display of the incoming number from the serial port, which appears as a blinking value (I couldn't think of a better term). I will provide a sample video of the output along with the code of the program.

My Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApp22
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort port;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Initialize the serial port.
            port = new SerialPort("COM13", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            port.Open();

            // Add an event handler for the DataReceived event.
            port.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
        }

        private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the data that was received.
            string data = port.ReadExisting();
            string[] parts = data.Split(' ');
            string weight = parts.Last();

            // Remove non-numeric characters from the weight.
            weight = Regex.Replace(weight, @"[^0-9]", "");

            // Trim the leading zeros from the weight.
            weight = weight.TrimStart('0');

            // Update the text box on the main thread.
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
                textBox1.Text = weight;
                textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

The output of my program is as follows, which I recorded in the form of a video.

https://kimiyakavan.com/1/200.webp

I expect the output that I desire. I have placed it in the following link.

https://kimiyakavan.com/1/201.webp

Comment: please skip the splits, the parts.Last(), the Regex.Replace(), and the TrimStart(), and show us what you ***actually*** read from the serial port. Also show us exactly what the documentation of your scale says about the data that it sends through the serial port.

Comment: In addition to the Mike's comment, I would like to add that serial port protocols typically have some sort of packets integrity check. And I don't see that you checking the integrity of the data you're receiving. Also, I don't see any logic that checks that you've actually read the entire packet (and not just a portion of it) before parsing the data (the `DataReceived` can be fired at any moment, it doesn't guarantee that the buffer contains exactly the single and entire packet).

Comment: Mr. Mike Nakis,
The data that is read from the serial port is as follows.

"P-000006\rP-000006\rP-000006\rP-000006\rP-000006\rP-000006\rP-000006\rP-000006\rP-000006\rP-000006\rP-000006\rP-000006\rP-000006
\rP-000006\r"

Comment: Mr. Serg,
Can you please provide me with some more details? I am new here and would appreciate further explanation.

Comment: @Siamak In serial communication, if you send 100 bytes, there is no guarantee that the receiver will receive 100 bytes at once. So, as Serg said, we need to send additional data like STX/ETX to indicate the start/end of the packet and then have the receiver interpret it and verify that all the data was received. The code in the body of this post doesn't implement that, so it doesn't know if the data it receives is "41" or "4" and "1", which is why it looks like it's updating and flashing every time an event occurs.

Comment: Use `port.NewLine = `\r` ;`, now you can use ReadLine() instead of ReadExisting and be sure you get just a single weight measurement.  Only call BeginInvoke() when the value is different.

Answer (score 0):

So, we have a data stream consisting of a packets like this one `P-000006\r`. Each packet starts with `P-` (let's call it `prefix`) and ends with `\r` (`suffix`). Between these prefix and suffix we have some digits, which representing the desired value.

We can receive data in parts, so the packets may be incomplete. All the following data is expeced inside `DataReceived` handler

- `P-`
- `P-000`
- `P-000006`
- `0006`
- `P-000006\r`
- `P-000006\rP-000006\rP-000006\r`
- `00006\rP-000006\rP-00000`
- ...

So, we have to accumulate the data until we get at least the one complete packet. Then we can get the weight from that packet, but if we got some data after that packet, then we want to save that data for future use. For example, if we got `00004\rP-000005\rP-000006`, then we will parse the value `5` (as the corresponding packet is the only complete) and store the `P-000006` part for future processing.

Simplified parser with accumulation:

```
public class Parser
{
    private StringBuilder sb = new();
    private const string prefix = "P-";
    private const char suffix = '\r';
    private static readonly int minLength = "P-0\r".Length; //minimal length of full packet
    
    private static readonly int prefixLen = prefix.Length;
    private const int suffixLen = 1;

    public bool TryParse(ReadOnlySpan<char> newData, out int weight)
    {
        weight = -1;
        if (TryFindEntirePacket(newData, out var packet, out var end))
        {
            //reset buffer
            sb.Clear();

            //add the "tail" of the data into the buffer for future usage
            sb.Append(newData[(end + 1)..]);

            //parse the value from the found packet
            var strW = packet[prefixLen..^suffixLen];
            return int.TryParse(strW, NumberStyles.None, null, out weight);
        }

        //Try adding a new piece of data to the previously received data and check again
        var newStr = sb.Append(newData).ToString();
        if (TryFindEntirePacket(newStr, out packet, out end))
        {
            //reset buffer and save the tail
            sb.Clear();
            sb.Append(newStr[(end + 1)..]);

            //parse the value from the found packet
            var strW = packet[prefixLen..^suffixLen];
            return int.TryParse(strW, NumberStyles.None, null, out weight);
        }
        
        return false;
    }

    private bool TryFindEntirePacket(ReadOnlySpan<char> str, out ReadOnlySpan<char> packet, out int end)
    {
        const int notFound = -1;
        var start = notFound;
        end = notFound;
        packet = null;

        if (str.Length < minLength)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var i = str.Length - 1;
        for (; i >= 0 && end == notFound; i--)
        {
            if (str[i] == suffix)
            {
                end = i;
            }
        }

        for (; i >= 1 && start == notFound; i--)
        {
            if (str[i] == prefix[1] && str[i - 1] == prefix[0])
            {
                start = i - 1;
            }
        }


        if (start != notFound && end != notFound)
        {
            packet = str[start..(end + 1)];
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage (trying to parse the `0001\rP-000002\rP-00` in parts and should get the value of '2' as a final result):

```
        var parser = new Parser();
        var res = parser.TryParse("0", out var w);
        Assert.False(res);

        res = parser.TryParse("001\rP", out w);
        Assert.False(res);

        res = parser.TryParse("-000", out w);
        Assert.False(res);

        res = parser.TryParse("002", out w);
        Assert.False(res);

        res = parser.TryParse("\rP-00", out w);
        Assert.True(res);
        Assert.Equal(2, w);
```